Why are pointers to data members callable in C++?
Under the "Callable" page at cppreference it states:

Notes: Pointers to data members are Callable, even though no function calls take place.

Pointers to function members makes sense: why are pointers to data members Callable if they can't be called?

Pointers to memebers are very useful as projection functions. Suppose you have struct S { int i; int j; } and you want to find an element in std::vector<S> vec by i = 1. You can do: std::ranges::find(vec, 1, &S::i);. No lamdas.

I would say "invocable" may be a more appropriate name because it directly relates to INVOKE but anyway "callable" is what we have in the standard now.

Pointers to data members are callable types by definition.
Note that this doesn't refer to the use of the call operator (), since data member pointers and member function pointers cannot have the () operator applied to them; however they can be invoked.
The exposition-only expression INVOKE (exposed through std::invoke) works with any callable type.
For a data member pointer f, INVOKE(f, t) expands to t.*f ([func.require] p1.4).
Thus, data member pointers act like a function that returns a member of an object.
Callable data member pointers are useful
They can be very useful as projections in the new C++20 algorithms:
struct S { int x; };
std::vector<S> range = /* ... */;

// sort range using std::ranges::less and using &S::x as a projection
std::ranges::sort(range, {}, &S::x);

Such a call to std::ranges::sort would sort range by comparing the x member of each S object.
This works because algorithms accept any callable type, not just types with a call operator.
Note on language development
Admittedly, the terminology is very confusing.
In hindsight, "callable types" should have been named "invocable types" instead.
There have also been proposals to add a () operator to member pointers; most recently, there is P1214: Pointer to Member Functions and Member Objects are just Callables!.

This sounds similar to a Python property, where accessing one via an instance really invokes the property's __get__ method with the instance as an argument.

@chepner Note that this doesn't refer to the use of the call operator ()  it's a definition from library API, not from language syntax (where pointers to member is a separate class of types, distinct from pointers to functions or other pointers). Essentially it says that functions which can accept callable object supposed to have an overload for a pointer-to-member.

Pointers to data members can be "called" in the sense that they can be invoked even though an actual function call does not happen. See Function objects ‒ a pointer to data member is "callable" by retrieving the member on a target object, which is also what std::invoke does when given a pointer to member.
As to why, I presume convenience. It is useful to be able to treat a pointer to member like a function that just retrieves the member, since there is generally nothing else you can do with such a thing, just like with function pointers.

The standard defines it this way. [func.def]/3

A callable type is a function object type ([function.objects]) or a pointer to member.

The standards defines INVOKE for pointers to data members.
func.require


Define INVOKE(f, t1 , t2 , …, tN ) as follows:
(1.4) - t1.*f when N = 1 and f is a pointer to data member of a class T and is_same_v<T, remove_cvref_t<decltype(t1)>> || is_base_of_v<T, remove_cvref_t<decltype(t1 )>> is true;
(1.5) - t1.get().*f when N = 1 and f is a pointer to data member of a class T and remove_cvref_t<decltype(t1 )> is a specialization of reference_wrapper;
(1.6) - (*t1 ).*f when N = 1 and f is a pointer to data member of a class T and t1 does not satisfy the previous two items;



Roughly, the invoke result of a data member is a data member value.

In C++, the term "callable" can take across multiple implications, particularly when referring to pointers to data members. Although the nomenclature may initially appear illogical, it aids in comprehending the context and the wider definition of "callable" in the context of C++.
In a specific sense pointers to data members are regarded as callable. This is mostly because of how they can be accessed, changed, and interacted with using syntax. This is the reason they are considered callable
Here’s an example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
public:
    int x;
    float y;
};

int main() {
    MyClass obj;
    obj.x = 10;
    obj.y = 3.14f;

    // Pointer to data member
    int MyClass::*pX = &MyClass::x;

    // Applying the pointer to the data member
    cout << "Value of x: " << obj.*pX << endl;  // Output: Value of x: 10

    return 0;
}

In this code, obj.*pX looks and behaves somewhat like calling a function, but in reality, it is accessing the x member of obj through a pointer.
